# How is ReturnUrl stored in a MVC4 Razor page when using HTML.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following Razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "registerForm", data_href = "/User/Account/Register" }))
{
    ....
}
```

This produces:

```
<form action="/User/Account/Register" class="form" data-href="/User/Account/Register" id="registerForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

I don't see any reference to ReturnUrl in the code produced. Can someone explain is this stored as part of the HTML?

Comment: Are you sure ViewBag.ReturnUrl is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason i was not getting desired returl parameter in form tag

> By writing this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
                new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, }, FormMethod.Post, null))
```

> Wanted This and it should write this in html

```
    <form action="/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FDashboard%2FIndex" method="post">
```

> But getting this in browser html

```
<form action="/Account/Login/Dashboard/Index" method="post">
```

**Solution:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
                new { backUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, }, FormMethod.Post, null))
```

> Will Produce this

```
<form action="/Account/Login?backUrl=%2FDashboard%2FIndex" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

lets have a look at your code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "registerForm", data_href = "/User/Account/Register" }))
{
    ....
}
```

the first param is the action method name, the second on is controller and the third param is [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493084%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) so when you specify the ReturnUrl, it become the part of route data params and in  your action method you can access it like

```
public ActionResult action(FormColection col, string ReturnUrl){
}
```